# Retrieve a key value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I've got a Calendar. Inside its code there's an Object and a JSON to it, which contains several properties such as

```
   [{"Date":"17-3-2015","Event":"Test drive","Participants":"John, George","Description":"Testing a new F30"},
    {"Date":"17-3-2015","Event":"Football match","Participants":"FCSM vs FCKK","Description":"New season start"},
    {"Date":"25-3-2015","Event":"Jane's Birthday","Participants":"Jane, John, Richard, Alice","Description":"Celebration with my friends"}]
```

But since that data is in localStorage I retrieved it via

```
var existEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'));
for(i=0; i<existEvents.length; i++) {
    var item = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    console.log(item);
};
```

`existEvents` = every new event in my Calendar

`console.log(item);` returns me the data typed above.

What I need is to retrieve every Date value (= key). So I pretend that

```
 item.Date
```

must work, but it doesn't. As well as

```
item[0].value
```

I tried it after having read this question + answers 
[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

What am I doing wrong? Please, help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to use the Array.ForEach(), where it can be also used to loop on objects having the value as the first parameter and the key (if exists) in the second. In your example the for each takes this array, and loops on it retrieving one object at a time.

This object has a `Date` key in it, so you can access it using the `obj.key`. However, it is always good to use the `.hasOwnProperty` to check if the key exists first.

You can also use the `forEach` to loop through the object keys and then you will be able to have the `obj/key`. For example, looping on every `obj` from the array loop will give you `obj => 17-3-2015 | key => Date` ... etc.

```
var x =  [{"Date":"17-3-2015","Event":"Test drive","Participants":"John, George","Description":"Testing a new F30"},
        {"Date":"17-3-2015","Event":"Football match","Participants":"FCSM vs FCKK","Description":"New season start"},
        {"Date":"25-3-2015","Event":"Jane's Birthday","Participants":"Jane, John, Richard, Alice","Description":"Celebration with my friends"}];

x.forEach(function(obj,key){console.log(obj.Date) });
```

Your code can be:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events')).forEach(function(obj,key){console.log(obj.Date) });
```

Comment: Nice short solution. Note, hoverer, that `Array.prototype.forEach` is only supported in IE 9+.

Comment: This answer is only short it is written all on one line. What is the advantage of using a foreach with an anonymous function when a for loop will suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to be going back into localstorage inside your for loop since you already have all of your data in the variable existEvents.

```
var existEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'));
for(i=0; i<existEvents.length; i++) {
    var item = existEvents[i];
    console.log(item);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 LocalStorage is an associative array storage with the `getItem` function grabbing one of the items. So,

```
localStorage.getItem ("somekey")
```

returns whatever variable `somekey` was set to. In your code snippet, the variable you are storing in the `localStorage` is a String that happens to be in JSON form. `JSON.parse ()` turns that JSON into the actual array represented by the String you've stored.

```
var existEvents = JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem ('events'));
for (var i = 0; i < existEvents.length; i++) {
    var item = existEvents [i];
    console.log(item);
};
```

`existEvents` is an Array object so you can access it like normal. After you've retrieved it from `localStorage` and parsed it, you no longer need to access `localStorage.getItem`.